# Methods of showing Field Extensions are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, extension-field

I understand that any finite extension $F(a, b)$ of a field $F$ is also a simple extension $F(c)$. The argument from *A book of Abstract Algebra* by Pinter resolves around writing $c = a + tb$ where $t\in F$. This immediately implies that $c$ is not unique then.

For example, for the finite extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ 2\sqrt{3})$. I know that for every simple extension $F(c)$ with a minimum polynomial of degree $n$, then $\{1, c, \ldots c^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $F(c)$ with scalars from $F$.

I am curious if I could show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ 2\sqrt{3})$ by showing that the basis vectors for one field extension can be written as a linear combination of the other field extension's vector basis.

I am doing this by showing that each element of the basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})$, which is $\{1, \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}, 5 + 2\sqrt{6}, 11\sqrt{2} + 9\sqrt{3}\}$, can be written as a linear combination of the basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ 2\sqrt{3})$ which happens to have the basis $\{1, \sqrt{2}+ 2\sqrt{3}, 14 + 4\sqrt{6}, 38\sqrt{2}+ 36\sqrt{3}\}$. I have been able to find the linear transformation for each vector in the basis, is this enough to show that the field extensions are equal?

Comment: Definitely enough. You are essentially showing that the new element is also an algebraic number of degree 4.

Comment: Call the two bases $\{a_1,\cdots,a_4\}=A$ and $\{b_1,\cdots,b_4\}=B$. Have you found constants $\{c_{ij}\}$ such that for each $i$, $a_j=\sum_ic_{ij}b_i$? That is, sixteen constants? Knowing that $A$ and $B$ both are bases, you’ve done all that’s necessary. No need to find the inverse matrix, for instance.

Comment: @PVanchinathan But showing an element is algebraic and of the same degree of the field extension shouldn't be enough because we could consider the fourth root of any prime number, and that will be algebraic and have degree 4 as well

Comment: @Lubin I am more concerned that even if i did not find the certain constants, that this approach is correct in showing that the field extensions are equal

Comment: Well, I think that the right argument for showing that $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3\,)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3\,)$ should be trivially modifiable to show that $K\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+2\sqrt3\,)$. (I’m not sure now that I remember this mythical “right” argument!)

Comment: Note that your initial paragraph isn't true for arbitrary fields $F$. It is true if $F$ has characteristic zero, though.